# Loading a kernel module at boot

Tags: kernel

I have an Intel NUC, and I've compiled a [kernel extension](https://github.com/milesp20/intel_nuc_led) to control the LED. It has created a `.ko` file at `/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/nuc_led.ko` (which matches `uname -r`). Manually loading the extension works great:

```
sudo modprobe wmi
sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/nuc_led.ko
echo 'ring,80,blink_medium,green' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/nuc_led > /dev/null
```

This works.

However the extension is not currently loaded at boot. I would like to put commands to turn the LED on and off in `rc.local` and `rc6.d/` but these are not working, I have to run the `modprobe` commands manually, and even then my file in `rc6.d/` (shown below) is not working - the LED remains on.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cat /etc/rc6.d/zz_led_off.sh
#! /bin/bash

echo 'ring,0,none,off' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/nuc_led > /dev/null

$ ls -la /etc/rc6.d/zz_led_off.sh | grep zz
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   79 Nov  9 10:07 zz_led_off.sh
```

Comment: why not compile directly into the kernel, instead of being a module?

Comment: @DougSmythies I'm not sure what that means, how would I compile it directly into the kernel?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was wrong. If I understand correctly, because it isn't part of the kernel code, but rather an extension to it, I don't think direct compile into the kernel is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the module to `/etc/modules`, in this case, add the following two lines:

```
wmi
nuc_led
```

Comment: Where do the `.ko` files need to be copied? How does the Linux find it?