# Run sudo commands on startup

Tags: startup, autostart

I need to run this command on startup, '''sudo modprobe apple_bce
sudo modprobe apple_ib_tb
sudo modprobe apple_ib_als''' and I can not have user input to activate it because it activates my laptop's speakers, track pad and keyboard drivers.

Comment: It sounds like what you *really* should be asking is how to [Configure kernel modules to load at boot](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/modules-load.d.5.html)

Comment: ... either that neat way or add the modules to the file  `/etc/modules` each module on a single new line ... Just the module name with no `sudo` nor `modprobe`

Comment: Thank you @Raffa that worked

Comment: just ad commands to /etc/rc.local

Comment: Commands run at system startup are all run as `root` (`UID 0`), so using `sudo` is redundant, unless you're `sudo`ing to some other userid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a kernel module at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091379/loading-a-kernel-module-at-boot)